# Can you pass JSON Data from Svelte Client side to Server and vice versa?

Tags: database, server, svelte, sveltekit, writefile

In the documentation you can "preload" server-side data and pass that like a prop to the client using a load function. That makes sense but lets say I'm building a direct message component and need to store user messages in a database, and not use localstorage. Is there a way to pass or update data to the server like fs.writeFileSync to update json backend? Right now I'm setting up an express server-side and svelte just in the front but ideally I'd love for sveltekit to eliminate express. Most info is just passing Data from back to front and thats it, and if you want more you have to signup to a third party db system like mongoDb or supabase, etc.. I just want to update a json file via the client side and have the client side respond to it on future visits.

I've tried localstorage and its not what I want, I want to avoid third party systems like mongo db. I just want Sveltekit to be the full solution without using express for a more robust server.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [+server routes](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server):

- Can input JSON
- Can output JSON
- Can access `fs.writeFileSync`

> As well as pages, you can define routes with a +server .ts  file
> (sometimes referred to as an 'API route' or an 'endpoint'), which
> gives you full control over the response. Your +server .ts  file
> exports functions corresponding to HTTP verbs like GET, POST, PATCH,
> PUT, DELETE, and OPTIONS that take a  RequestEvent  argument and
> return a Response object.

Basically, +server routes can replace both express and third party systems like MongoDB.